# App identifier and other data not filling into Installation object

Tags: parse-platform

I have a new iOS 8 app that is doing push notifications. Unlike the apps I've developed before, it doesn't seem to fill in the Installation object with data. Fields like: appIdentifier, appName, appVersion, badge, parseVersion, timeZone.

It does however fill in: deviceToken, deviceType, installationId.

So this is problematic because I don't know which App to push to now! HELP!

Oh and for extra bonus, I have a new column called "Business" which is a pointer to a Business object. I would LOVE to list the ID for that business within the App too. That way it's already pre-associated. Hell, if even that part worked, I could successfully push message.

Comment: I'm working on the same thing at the moment, I've got everything to fill in apart from deviceToken. What language are you using I'd be happy to share my code

Comment: I'm working on the same thing i got only device-token but not getting time Zone, App identifier, App Name, App version etc.